# Custom DropList in WFFM

Tags: wffm, fieldtype

We created a custom drop list in WFFM to hold values populated from DB.

The problem is the value is not getting selected in the drop list.

Example: If the user's country is UK, the drop list shows the first country that is present in the dropdownlist.

The custom droplist html is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Value, Model.Items, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Can you check if there's an item with Selected = true in Model.items?

Comment: Hi Saggi ,Can you please share the logic how you created custom drop down